# Where do I get the config for dart launch in VSCode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm working on a flutter web project with VSCode and I noticed some inconsistency between the app when it is rendered by the VSCode debugger or through the command line. The app (color, alignment, font ...) doesn't look the same in both scenarios.

For example, here is what is rendered when I launch the debug in VSCode:

[image]

here is the configuration in the `launch.json`

```json
{
    "name": "Launch",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "dart",
    "program": "lib/main.dart"
},
```

---

And here is what is rendered when I run the command

```
flutter run lib/main.dart
```

[image]

---

I managed to "fix" the command line display by adding the flag `--web-renderer canvaskit` to the command line.

---

Now, what I would like to know is what are the settings used by the VSCode debugger, and where to find them /modify them?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Selection menu for vscode]

Go to "open configurations" from Run menu

There, in the `launch.json` file, you can add your args in this format

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for this but my goal is not to customize my `launch.json` file with new parameters (this works well). My goal is to know what are the default parameters when I don't specify any.